# Problem with eval function

Tags: javascript

Hello I get a weird error in this code:

```
 function validateForm(aform) {
  var s="";

  //check if form has validator arr
  if (aform.validatorArr)  {
    //Iterate over Form elements
    for (var i=0;i<aform.validatorArr.length;i++)  {
      eval("var anelem=document.forms."+aform.name+"."+aform.validatorArr[i][1]);
      var pattern=getPatternByName(aform.validatorArr[i][2]);

      if (aform.validatorArr[i][4]=="radio") {
        var fv="";

        eval("var chkArray=aform."+aform.validatorArr[i][1]+";");

        for (j=0;j<chkArray.length;j++)  {
          if (chkArray[j].checked) {
            fv=chkArray[j].value;
          }
        }

        if (validateValue(fv,pattern)==false)  {
          s+=aform.validatorArr[i][3]+"\n";
        }

      } else {
        if (validateField(anelem,pattern)==false)  {
          s+=aform.validatorArr[i][3]+"\n";
        }
      }
    }

    //Report errors
    if (s!="") {
      alert(s);
      return false;
    }

  }

  return true;
}
```

missing ] after element list
Line 217

This is line 217:

```
 eval("var anelem=document.forms."+aform.name+"."+aform.validatorArr[i][1]);
```

Any idea's what's wrong?

### Update

This is how de function is called: submitForm('formbuilder_form');
Which is identical to the form name:

```
    <form name="formbuilder_form" method="POST" action="processform.php" style="margin:0px">
```

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

In onw of the form element someone decided it was good to have it like this:

Js doesn't like this.

Thanks for helping everyone.

Comment: btw, you don't need to use `eval`: `document.forms[aform.name][aform.validatorArr[i][1]]` should work just fin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you do this?
You should do this:

```
var anelem=document.forms[aform.name][aform.validatorArr[i][1]];
```

But from updated post it is understood that aform is a string - not an object. So you should get an object first.

```
aform=ocument.forms[aform]
```

Comment: Even better - `document.forms[aform.name].elements[aform.validatorArr[i][1]];`

Comment: Error means you have no form named aform.name on the page.

Comment: how do you call validateForm(aform)

Comment: from a submit button within the form

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to use **`eval`**. Try this instead:

```
var anelem = document.forms[aform.name][aform.validatorArr[i][1]];
```

Comment: this gives me the error:

document.forms[aform.name] is undefined

Line 218

Answer (score 2):

`forms.fish` is the same as `forms['fish']` for all JavaScript objects. So you can use []s to get a property whose name is stored in a string from an object instead of evil `eval`.

Top tip: if you find yourself ever using `eval`, you are probably making a mistake.

> "document.forms."+aform.name

is particularly comical because you're trying to get the `name` of a form object and access the form with that name — which is the same form object you started out with!

However:

> submitForm('formbuilder_form')

is wrong whether you're using `eval` or []: you're passing a string into submitForm instead of a form object. A string does not have a `name` property.

And having submitForm separate from the normal form submission process is messy and breaks non-JavaScript UAs. If you write:

```
<form method="post" action="processform.php" onsubmit="return submitForm(this);">
   ...
</form>
```

then 'aform' in the function will be the form object and you can access elements as simply as:

```
var anelem= aform[aform.validatorArr[i][1]];
```

without ever having to worry about `document.forms`, scripting submit buttons or form names. Although, to avoid name clashes on form properties, this is better:

```
var anelem= aform.elements[aform.validatorArr[i][1]];
```